# Creating a custom view and reusing the same view

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a Table layout which consists of five table rows. Each table row have a custom view which renders some graph and a custom textview. My Layout looks like following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <com.company.views.FirstView
        android:id="@+id/firstView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".80"
        android:background="#000000" />
    <com.company.views.FirstTextView
        android:id="@+id/firstTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".20"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:textColor="#00FF00"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:digits="1234567890"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:scrollbars = "vertical"/>
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <com.company.views.SecondView
        android:id="@+id/secondView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".80"
        android:background="#000000" />
    <com.company.views.SecondTextView
        android:id="@+id/secondTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".20"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:textColor="#FFFF00"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:digits="1234567890"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:scrollbars = "vertical"/>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

The above code is working (I have taken some code out for the sake of explanation) but the problem is that my firstview and secondview looks very similar in functionality and code and the same goes for my firstTextView and secondTextView.

The question is instead of having five different custom views I want only one custom view and reuse it so the layout looks like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <com.company.views.FirstView
        android:id="@+id/firstView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".80"
        android:background="#000000" />
    <com.company.views.FirstTextView
        android:id="@+id/firstTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".20"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:textColor="#00FF00"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:digits="1234567890"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:scrollbars = "vertical"/>
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <com.company.views.FirstView
        android:id="@+id/secondView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".80"
        android:background="#000000" />
    <com.company.views.FirstTextView
        android:id="@+id/secondTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".20"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:textColor="#FFFF00"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:digits="1234567890"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:scrollbars = "vertical"/>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

The Problem is that when from my firstTextView java class i do the following

```
private void init(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.firstTextView);
    textView.setText("My Awesome Text");;
}
```

the code breaks with an inflate exception. I am stuck here as I don't know what I am doing wrong. Is there any other way to achieve the desired outcome. Or am I missing something obvious.

My FirstTextView looks like following

```
public class FirstTextView extends AppCompatTextView {
private int spinnerText=120;
private float oldY=0;
private TextView textView;
private Context context;
private PopupWindow mPopupWindow;

public FirstTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    init(null, 0);
}

public FirstTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    init(attrs, 0);

}

public FirstTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.context = context;
    init(attrs, defStyle);
}

private void init(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    //cant do that as the findviewbyid return null
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.firstView);
    textView.setOnTouchListener(handleTouch);
    // Here i want to find which textview firstView or SecondView. 
    //if(firstview)
       //textView.setText(""+Physiology.getInstance().Model1.getValue());
    //else 
      //textView.setText(""+Physiology.getInstance().Model2.getValue());  
     textView.setText(""+Physiology.getInstance().Model2.getValue());
}

@Override
public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
    String newText="";
    if(text.length()>0){
        newText=String.valueOf(text);
        int textasNumber=Integer.valueOf(newText);
        Physiology.getInstance().mBloodPressure.setSystolic(textasNumber);
        newText= Physiology.getInstance().mBloodPressure.getSystolic() + "/" +  (int)Physiology.getInstance().mBloodPressure.mDiastolic;
    }

    super.setText(newText,type);
}

public void onTextViewClick(View v) {
    // Initialize a new instance of LayoutInflater service
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // Inflate the custom layout/view
    NumberPadView customView = (NumberPadView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.number_popup,null);

    // Initialize a new instance of popup window
    mPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(
            customView,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );

    customView.init(Physiology.getInstance().mBloodPressure.getSystolic(),mPopupWindow,this);

    // Finally, show the popup window at the center location of root
    mPopupWindow.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
}
  }
```

Comment: We don't know what the ``FirstTextView`` code is, I guess it extends ``TextView``

Comment: yes firstTextView and secondTextView both extends TextView

Comment: I think more code is needed, for context. Is not ``layout_width`` required? I thougth it was, put your stacktrace form logcat.

Comment: Yes layout width is required and is also present in my code i just didn't copied all the code to this post because the post maybe gets bloated.

Comment: Is the problem that you want to have two different text values for `firstTextView` and `secondTextView`?

Comment: @BenP. yes but only having one custom TextView

Comment: Is there anything else at all that will be different between them?

Comment: The only difference is the text.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The code snippets you have posted here are missing much of the things we need to understand what is going on. Variables are not declared and you posted a method without the enclosing class. Please [edit] your question to include these and any other necessary details so that we can help. Also include the full stack trace for the exception.

Comment: Updated the code for better understanding of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text is the *only* thing you want to change, I would just put the text in the XML file directly:

```
<com.company.views.FirstTextView
    android:id="@+id/firstTextView"
    android:text="my first text
    .../>
```

```
<com.company.views.FirstTextView
    android:id="@+id/secondTextView"
    android:text="my second text
    .../>
```

Even though you're using a subclass of `TextView`, you can still use its attributes as normal.

---

You could also query the view ID from within the view itself if you need to do something special:

```
private void init(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    if (getId() == R.id.firstTextView) {
        ...
    } else if (getId() == R.id.secondTextView) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Overall I would say that this isn't a great idea, since your views should (in general) work without knowing what their own ID is... but you could still do it if it's what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what if I want to keep changing the text of the textview when user clicks on the textview

Comment: I know I can add a click event and then change the Text but I want to differentiate which view was clicked to find the Text i want to set.

Comment: I think you're going to have to provide more of your original code so we can see what the differences are

Comment: I have updated the question so it has my original code. I will try to see if getid() works because if i can get the id then i think I have solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. Your second edit put me in the right direction.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea for having a logic based on id. If i don't do that then I end up with a lot of redundant code as my custom views have more or less the same functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Since your custom views extend TextView, there is no need to do findViewById. Your object itself is already the view.

So you can simply in your init() call setText("even awesomer");

Your code breaks, because findViewById returns null and then you get a NPE trying to call setText() on that.

To differentiate between Views within the View, just use getId().

But from your questions, I think you just want to treat your custom views like any other view. In that case, do what you do for other views. In the Activity's onCreate(), after setContentView(), do your

```
firstView = findViewById(R.id.firstView);
firstTextView = findViewById(R.id.firstTextView);
secomdView = findViewById(R.id.secondView);
secondTextView = findViewById(R.id.secondTextView);

firstView.setText("Hi there");
...
```

Comment: But i want to find the view by id so i know which text to set.

Comment: But where is ``init()`` being called, I thougth it was in ``activity``, if it's from view class of course it's wrong

Comment: Each init is called from constructor of each java view class.

Comment: So, are you calling ``findViewById(R.id.firstTextView);`` inside your custom ``TextView`` class?

Comment: yes its called from inside the custom TextView class but I dont know if what I am doing is right as I am a newbie to android.

Comment: You don't have to find anything from within the custom view, you are already in the custom view class.  A view cannot find itself with findViewById().  This answer is correct.

Comment: I am not saying that its the wrong answer but I am interested in how to differentiate the views so I know which text to set.

Comment: You must find the views from within the table layout is being created, in your fragment or activity class.

Comment: I didn't need to find any view. getId() method worked. Thanks alot for the help.